# ¿Hay alguna manera de aplicar un espacio definido por mí mismo entre rows del sistema grid de bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

tengo aplicado el system grid de bootstrap en un formulario de html, sucede que entre rows (filas) creo un espacio a través de etiquetas br que según mi criterio y necesidad es muy grande:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo señalado en amarillo es a lo que me refiero, de otro modo si no agrego las etiquetas br entonces sucede todo lo contrario, se pegan demasiado las filas que en este caso son inputs, quedando de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                <label>Nombre: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre" maxlength="50">
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                <label for="floatingSelectGrid">Tipo: </label>
                <select class="form-control" aria-label="Floating label select example">
                    <option selected>Selecciones...</option>
                    <option>Otro</option>
                </select>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                <label for="floatingInputGrid">Modelo: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control col-auto" placeholder="Ingrese Modelo" maxlength="50"> 
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                <label for="floatingInputGrid">Serial: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Serial" maxlength="50">
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
```

¿Habrá alguna manera del system grid para definir ese espacio con un determinado valor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar las [utilidades para espaciado](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/spacing/) de bootstrap.

Por ejemplo, mt-2, que indica **m** (margin), **t** (top), **2** (un número que indica el espaciado a aplicar. En [su documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/spacing/#notation) se explica detalladamente.).

En tu caso podrías aplicarlo en tu segundo **row**:

```
<div class="row mt-2">
```

Y si lo necesitas con un determinado valor, tal como preguntas, debes aplicar el estilo en el atributo style:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
```

Comment: Gracias muchas gracias amigo, lo que necesitaba, éxitos!